# What is a name of tall image control of the left side of "Finished/Completing" page of Inno Setup installer wizard?

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I would like to modify the *height* property of this bitmap control that is shown in the last setup page of a Inno Setup installer:

[image]

The problem is that I don't know the name of that control. It must have the same height like this other bitmap control that is in the first page of the installer:

[image]

This is my current script for the control sizes and positions:

```
// ******************
// UI Personalization
// ******************

const
  Custom_Height = 570;

var
  DefaultTop,
  DefaultLeft,
  DefaultHeight,
  DefaultBackTop,
  DefaultNextTop,
  DefaultCancelTop,
  DefaultBevelTop,
  DefaultOuterHeight: Integer;

procedure InitializeWizard();

begin

  DefaultTop := WizardForm.Top;
  DefaultLeft := WizardForm.Left;
  DefaultHeight := WizardForm.Height;
  DefaultBackTop := WizardForm.BackButton.Top;
  DefaultNextTop := WizardForm.NextButton.Top;
  DefaultCancelTop := WizardForm.CancelButton.Top;
  DefaultBevelTop := WizardForm.Bevel.Top;
  DefaultOuterHeight := WizardForm.OuterNotebook.Height;

// Pages Size
  WizardForm.Height := Custom_Height;
  WizardForm.InnerPage.Height := WizardForm.InnerPage.Height + (Custom_Height - DefaultHeight);
  WizardForm.LicensePage.Height := WizardForm.LicensePage.Height + (Custom_Height - DefaultHeight);

// Controls Location
  WizardForm.BackButton.Top := DefaultBackTop + (Custom_Height - DefaultHeight);
  WizardForm.Bevel.Top := DefaultBevelTop + (Custom_Height - DefaultHeight);
  WizardForm.CancelButton.Top := DefaultCancelTop + (Custom_Height - DefaultHeight);
  WizardForm.LicenseAcceptedRadio.Top := WizardForm.LicenseAcceptedRadio.Top + (Custom_Height - DefaultHeight);
  WizardForm.LicenseNotAcceptedRadio.Top := WizardForm.LicenseNotAcceptedRadio.Top + (Custom_Height - DefaultHeight);
  WizardForm.NextButton.Top := DefaultNextTop + (Custom_Height - DefaultHeight);
  WizardForm.Top := DefaultTop - (Custom_Height - DefaultHeight) div 2;

// Controls Size
  WizardForm.InfoBeforeMemo.Height := (Custom_Height - (DefaultHeight / 2));
  WizardForm.InnerNotebook.Height :=  WizardForm.InnerNotebook.Height + (Custom_Height - DefaultHeight);
  WizardForm.LicenseMemo.Height := WizardForm.LicenseMemo.Height + (Custom_Height - DefaultHeight);
  WizardForm.OuterNotebook.Height := WizardForm.OuterNotebook.Height + (Custom_Height - DefaultHeight);
  WizardForm.Taskslist.Height := (Custom_Height - (DefaultHeight / 2));
  WizardForm.WizardBitmapImage.Height := (Custom_Height - (DefaultHeight / 5));

end;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `WizardBitmapImage2` of type `TBitmapImage`.

---

See [`Projects/Wizard.dfm.txt`](https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/blob/ee1e25f0e786bddff719afd76b9447b13d5e9748/Projects/Wizard.dfm.txt#L628):

```pascal
...
object FinishedPage: TNewNotebookPage
  Color = clWindow
  ParentColor = False
  object WizardBitmapImage2: TBitmapImage
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 164
    Height = 314
    BackColor = clWindow
  end
  ...
end
...
```